# IOT Central Hub Gauges

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-central, azure-iot-hub-device-management

I want to make a gauge for temperature on the template/dashboard. Does anyone know if you can do gauges (Not pie chart) in iot central?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Welcome to StackOverflow](http://StackOverflow.com/tour) - Please read our [ask] page and [edit] your question to improve it.
Good questions tend to receive quicker, better answers from the community.

Comment: Be sure and check the answer as correct if you find it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Azure IoT Central does not support custom tiles. These are the only supported tiles.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-central/core/howto-add-tiles-to-your-dashboard#tile-types

If you want to do custom projects, look at Azure IoT Solution Accelerators https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/iot-accelerators/

Comment: @Jon Watkins please mark as answer if the above suggestion helped.